# IntelliJ IDEA: Error:scalac: Class javax.servlet.ServletException not found - continuing with a stub

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

IntelliJ IDEA suddenly fails compiling my code with the following error message in the compiler output:

> Error:scalac: Class javax.servlet.ServletException not found -
>   continuing with a stub.

Versions: Scala 2.11, Java 8, Sbt 0.13.7, IntelliJ IDEA CE 14. **Not** using sbt-idea plugin.

[image: compiler output with Class javax.servlet.ServletException not found error]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

Go to `File > Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs`

- Remove unnecessary SDKs (not sure this is required but I had both Java 7 an 8, kept the latter only)
- At the bottom of the SDK Classpath tab, click + and add the following jar (modify path if necessary, depends on install method, operating system and Java version): `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar`
- Recompile the project
- Profit